# Understanding Rails Params + Graphql Mutation interaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql

I have two rails app, one is a graphql API and the other one is a REST API App as well.
Let's call the graphql app `graphi` and the REST app `resti`.

1. graphi sends data to resti.
2. resti then talk's to an external API, get's a response from that external API, and talks back to graphi with a nice response.

Ok, so graphi has a mutation called vendor. which can look like this:

```
mutation {
  createVendor(
    input: {
      vendorId: 2,
      quoteType: "renter",
      renterData: {
        firstName: "Tony",
        lastName: "Stark",
        email: "tony@starkindustries",
        phoneType: "mobile",
        phone: "6504881234",
        requestType: "renter",
        address1: "123 Main Street",
        addressCity: "Palo Alto",
        addressState: "CA",
        addressZip: "94301",
        dob: "1990-07-22"
      }
    }
  ) 
}
```

Then I send this data through httparty like this on the `create_vendor.rb (mutation file)`:

```
class CreateVendor < Mutations::BaseMutation
    description 'Create a vendor'
    argument :vendor_id, ID, required: false
    argument :quote_type, String, required: true
    argument :renter_data, Types::RenterVendorType, required: false
    field :vendor, Types::VendorType, null: false


    def resolve(args)
          response = HTTParty.post(
            'http://localhost:3001/api/v2/vendor', <-- this sends data to resti
            body: JSON.parse(args.to_json),
            headers: AUTHORIZATION_HEADERS
          )
         if response.success?
           puts "Cool, I was successfull"
         else
           puts "I wasn't successful"
         end
    end
end
```

Once graphi sends data to resti, resti server looks like this:

```
Processing by Api::V2::VendorController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"vendor_id"=>"2", "quote_type"=>"renter", "renter_data"=>{"first_name"=>"Tony", "last_name"=>"Stark", "email"=>"tony@starkindustries", "phone_type"=>"mobile", "phone"=>"6504881234", "request_type"=>"renter", "address1"=>"123 Main Street", "address_city"=>"Palo Alto", "address_state"=>"CA", "address_zip"=>"94301", "dob"=>"1990-07-22"}}
```

Now, this isn't graphql stuff anymore, this passes to be a hash with one nested parameter.

On resti's controller I have something like to to `permit vendor params`

```
def create_vendor_params
    params.require(:vendor).permit(
      :vendor_id, :quote_type, renter_data: %i[first_name last_name email phone_type phone request_type address1 address_city address_state address_zip DOB]
    )
  end
```

### THE PROBLEM

When I go through this flow I recieve this issue on the resti server:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: vendor
Did you mean?  vendor_id
               renter_data
               action
               quote_type):
```

And when I test this exact same thing on Postman using this data structure:

```
{   "vendor": {
        "vendor_id": 2,
        "quote_type": "renter",
        "renter_data": {
            "first_name":"Tony",
            "last_name":"Stark",
            "email":"tony@starkindustries.com",
            "phone_type":"mobile",
            "phone":"6504881234",
            "request_type":"renter",
            "address1":"123 Main Street",
            "address_city":"Palo Alto",
            "address_state":"CA",
            "address_zip":"94301",
            "DOB":"1990-07-22"
        }
    }
}
```

I recieve this below:

```
#<ActionController::Parameters {"vendor"=>#<ActionController::Parameters (#<ActionController::Parameters this  piece of code is ruining everything,) {"_id"=>2, "quote_type"=>"renter", "renter_data"=>{"first_name"=>"Tony", "last_name"=>"Stark", "email"=>"tony@starkindustries.com", "phone_type"=>"mobile", "phone"=>"6504881234", "request_type"=>"renter", "address1"=>"123 Main Street", "address_city"=>"Palo Alto", "address_state"=>"CA", "address_zip"=>"94301", "DOB"=>"1990-07-22"}} permitted: false>, "controller"=>"api/v2/vendor", "action"=>"create"} permitted: false>
```

Now there's something I can't understand why this happens. When I `byebug` on this piece of code:

```
def create_vendor_params
    params.require(:vendor).permit(
      :vendor_id, :quote_type, renter_data: %i[first_name last_name email phone_type phone request_type address1 address_city address_state address_zip DOB]
    )
    byebug
  end
```

And I manually do this:

```
(byebug) params.require(:vendor).permit(
:vendor_id, :quote_type, renter_data: %i[first_name last_name email phone_type phone request_type address1 address_city address_state address_zip DOB]
)
```

it prints out this:

```
#<ActionController::Parameters {"vendor_id"=>2, "quote_type"=>"renter", "renter_data"=>#<ActionController::Parameters {"first_name"=>"Tony", "last_name"=>"Stark", "email"=>"tony@starkindustries.com", "phone_type"=>"mobile", "phone"=>"6504881234", "request_type"=>"renter", "address1"=>"123 Main Street", "address_city"=>"Palo Alto", "address_state"=>"CA", "address_zip"=>"94301", "DOB"=>"1990-07-22"} permitted: true>} permitted: true>
```

It get's permitted!!

Why is this happening? How does graphql structure data? I will really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The params you sent to `resti` don't have the right shape. If you look closely the params aren't nested under a `vendor` as they were when you sent them through Postman.

Your mutation should have the following structure
mutation

```
  createVendor(
    input: {
      vendor: {
        vendorId: 2,
        quoteType: "renter",
        renterData: {
          firstName: "Tony",
          lastName: "Stark",
          email: "tony@starkindustries",
          phoneType: "mobile",
          phone: "6504881234",
          requestType: "renter",
          address1: "123 Main Street",
          addressCity: "Palo Alto",
          addressState: "CA",
          addressZip: "94301",
          dob: "1990-07-22"
        }
      }
    }
  )
```